# How to force a subclass to use a superclass variable?

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

I am using java and I would like to force all of my subclasses to use the variables of the superclass.
The superclass is abstract and the subclasses implement all of its methods but not the variables.
Is there any way I can force the subclasses to use also the variables of the superclass?

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "forcing the sub classes to use" ? There is nothing to do with variables apart from holding the values. Its all about methods/operations

Comment: What do you mean by *force*?

Comment: You can't force the subclass to do so. Any of the implementing methods/constructors/initializers can declare own their variables, ignoring those of the superclass.

Comment: You have a better chance of forcing the developers who write the sub-classes to use those variables. I suggest you do a code review of their work, if this is a serious concern. Or you could let the developers do their job rather than put such constraints on them.

Comment: what I meant is that if the superclass is abstract, then the subclass is forced to implement all of the methods of the superclass. I have a superclass that is abstract and it has about 7 subclasses. What I want is to declare 4 field variables on the superclass that all the subclasses will use, each subclass with its own implementation of the variables. For example, String phone will have a different value on each subclass.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot "force" the subclass to use your variables. But maybe you are looking for the [Template Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). This way, you can define a **template method** in the abstract superclass which defines the structure and the general working of your class. It calls the **hook methods** which are abstract and have to be provided by implementing classes. You can make it final to prevent subclasses from overriding the template method. Then the subclasses have to implement the abstract hook methods provided, but cannot override the template method.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `super` is most of the times used in conjunction to accessing superclass methods, most of the times a constructor from the parent class .

However, you can also use `super` to access fields of the superclass.

Here is an example of the usage for accessing fields.

```
public class Base {

    public int a = 1;
    protected int b = 2;
    private int c = 3;

    public Base(){

    }
}

public class Extended extends Base{

    public int a = 4;
    protected int b = 5;
    private int c = 6;

    public Extended(){

    }

    public void print(){
        //Fields from the superclass
        System.out.println(super.a);
        System.out.println(super.b);
        System.out.println(super.c); // not possible

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Extended ext = new Extended();
        ext.print();
    }
```

You can always rename the fields in your subclasses not to conflict, but if you want to distinguish a method parameter or local variable from the superclass field, use `super` as you would use `this`

Answer (score 0):

Just make the field protected, meaning that it should be visible to all derived classes and can use them in subclasses. If that is what you are tying to imply by saying force.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. All you need is to let the subclass inherit the superclass through inheritance. this would allow your subclass implement functions of your superclass.

For a more detailed reference kindly visit this link: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_04.htm

Comment: He already uses inheritance. The question is about the superclass's variables.

Comment: I think he should be able to use the variables through constructors?

Comment: If you'll try to study Inheritance deeper you'll know that you could use anything that the class you inherited has. you just need to call them properly to utilize their effectiveness.

Comment: would you like me to create a reference program showing variables of a super class being implemented on at least 3 subclass?

Comment: No thanks. Also you cannot "implement variables of a super class", you can use them if they are visible. Also this still does not answer the original question.

Comment: all you need to do is to invoke a constructor. Just like what I had told you earlier, you could use constructor to use the variables. use `super(constructor_name)` then at the bottom use `this.variable_of_the_subclass = variable_of_superclass`

Comment: Why do you reassign the superclass's variable to a variable of the subclass? And why do you insist on using a constructor? Just use ``super.variable_of_superclass`` wherever you need it. And this STILL does not answer the original question. The question is about **forcing** a subclass to use the superclass's variables. Take a look at the other answers since you don't seem to believe me.

Comment: what I meant is that if the superclass is abstract, then the subclass is forced to implement all of the methods of the superclass. I have a superclass that is abstract and it has about 7 subclasses. What I want is to declare 4 field variables on the superclass that all the subclasses will use, each subclass with its own implementation of the variables. For example, String phone will have a different value on each subclass.

Comment: I think it is just like my program for testing having animal as a super class then having sub classes such as mammal, reptile and the lots.

Answer (score 0):

Like someone said here you can use the template design pattern which will ensure that steps of an algorithm is given in a method so this way you can have the variable used in a method that can be used in a sub class.

The other approach would be to set the access modifier as "protected" which ensures that the subclasses that inherits from the super class can use the variables in the super class